# How to give ctrl + c to a process in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, command-line, vmware

I am trying to create a backgroundworker which create a process, that makes some ovf commands. In between I try to abort the operation by sending ctrl+c. There are similar questions on this site, but none has solved the problem.

```
private void DeployOVF()
{
    p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("ovftool.exe", "--machineOutput "+ FileName + " vi://uname:pwd@Ip Address");
    pi.UseShellExecute = false;
    pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    pi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo = pi;
    p.Start();
    StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;
    string myString;
    bool progressStarted = false;
    while ((myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Logic to display the progress
    }
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}
```

Here is where i send my ctrl+c to abort the progress,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p.StandardInput.Write("\x3");
    p.StandardInput.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just kill the process....

Comment: try sending SendKeys.Send("^(c)") in button1_Click.

Comment: Kill doesn't cancel it. I tried it and the ovf just gets hanged, it doesnt get cancel.

SendKeys.Send("^(c)") is also not working, I guess it sends ctrl+c to the window, but the requirement is to send ctrl+c to process

Comment: When you ctrl-c from the command line, it doesn't just send a literal "ctrl-c" to the program, it fires off a Signal Interrupt or SIGINT.

Comment: Did you try `p.CloseMainWindow();`?

Comment: @kamaraj6990 also, when replying to comments please use `@` to notify the user you reply to otherwise he won't see your reply.

Answer (score 2):

If the process is responding (i.e. its foreground thread is responding to signals), then you should use:

```
p.CloseMainWindow();
```

If not, you should be able to abort the process (uncleanly) with `Kill`:

```
p.Kill();

//Then wait for the process to end
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
```

Comment: Kill doesn't cancel it. I tried it and the ovf just gets hanged, it doesnt get cancel

Comment: If Kill doesn't cancel it, can you see if it's possible to kill the process from Windows Task Manager.  If you can't kill it from there, the process is stuck (as are you).

Comment: I tried killing it through task manager and the deployment process(invoked by the command) gets hanged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this will help, since I'm not familiar with `ofv`, but maybe try [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell#stopping-a-command). It has a multi-platform implementation that supports sending the `Ctrl + C` signal to an app.

```
var command = Command.Run("dotnet", "run", "--project", "C:\MyRepo\MyProj\MyProj.csproj");

// Business logic here...

await command.TrySignalAsync(CommandSignal.ControlC);
```

I was trying to use one ASP.Net Core app to send a `Ctrl + C` signal to another ASP.Net Core app and `MedallionShell` worked like a charm!